# Combine 3 functions into one in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

**I tried to combine these 3 functions into one, but after I did that, it won`t work.
can you help me combine those?**

```
function showForm(id, name) {
    document.getElementById('submitForm').style.display = "block";
    if (id == 0) {
        document.getElementById('submitForm').style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'block';
    }
}

function TestForm(id, name) {
    document.getElementById('TestFormSubmit').style.display = "block";
    if (id == 0) {
        document.getElementById('TestFormSubmit').style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'block';
    }
}

function FormOne(id, name) {
    document.getElementById('FormOneSubmit').style.display = "block";
    if (id == 0) {
        document.getElementById('FormOneSubmit').style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

If it needed, this is HTML, I use JSFiddle, after run it, choose form on right side, then it will shows "download form" but I don`t know how to do that.

```
<form name="forms" class="form1" id="first">
    <br />
    <p style="text-align: left;" class="form1">Choosing to Make A Difference</p>
    <select id="dropdownMenu" name="budget" onchange="javascript: showForm(document.getElementById('dropdownMenu').value);">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="#">Change Form</option>
        <option value="#">Scholarships and Grants</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="submitForm" style="display: none; position:absolute; margin-top:-20px;">
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Download Form" onclick="window.open(forms.budget.value,'newtab'+forms.budget.value)" />
    </div>
    <br />
</form>
<form name="forms" class="form1" id="second">
    <br />
    <p style="text-align: left;" class="form1">Choosing to Make A Difference</p>
    <select id="TestFormDropdown" name="budget" onchange="javascript: TestForm(document.getElementById('TestFormDropdown').value);">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="#">Change Form</option>
        <option value="#">Scholarships and Grants</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="TestFormSubmit" style="display: none; position:absolute; margin-top:-20px;">
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Download Form" onclick="window.open(forms.budget.value,'newtab'+forms.budget.value)" />
    </div>
    <br />
</form>

<form name="forms" class="form1" id="second">
    <br />
    <p style="text-align: left;" class="form1">Choosing to Make A Difference</p>
    <select id="FormOneDropdown" name="budget" onchange="javascript: FormOne(document.getElementById('FormOneDropdown').value);">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="#">Change Form</option>
        <option value="#">Scholarships and Grants</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="FormOneSubmit" style="display: none; position:absolute; margin-top:-20px;">
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Download Form" onclick="window.open(forms.budget.value,'newtab'+forms.budget.value)" />
    </div>
    <br />
</form>
```

Comment: What is `i`? Where does it come from?

Comment: Please check the HTML

Comment: Still the same question.

Comment: @PM 77-1  I think I need add a var statement right? I mean declare variable i

Comment: Where does it get its **value** from?

Comment: I`m kinda confused right now. So would you mind add those in JSFiddle and test it???    I`m beginner...

Comment: Is it **your** code?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
function showForm (id, name)  { 
    document.getElementById('submitForm').style.display = "block";
    if (id == 0) 
        document.getElementById('submitForm').style.display = "none";
     else 
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'block';
    }
```

JavaScript statements can be grouped together in code blocks, inside curly brackets {...}.

Comment: After plug in HTML, the second form and third form won`t give me "download form "text......

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one?

```
var functionCollections = {
showForm : function(id, name) {
    document.getElementById('submitForm').style.display = "block";
    if (id == 0) {
        document.getElementById('submitForm').style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'block';
    }
},
TestForm : function(id, name) {
document.getElementById('TestFormSubmit').style.display = "block";
    if (id == 0) {
        document.getElementById('TestFormSubmit').style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'block';
    }
},
FormOne : function(id, name) {
    document.getElementById('FormOneSubmit').style.display = "block";
    if (id == 0) {
        document.getElementById('FormOneSubmit').style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

};

and on the html instead using `showForm(id, name);` use `functionCollections.showForm(id, name);`