# Javascript combine 2 functions into one

Tags: javascript

I have similar problem with this: [Combine 3 functions into one in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063215/combine-3-functions-into-one-in-javascript)

I have functions:

```
test: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < settings.columns.test.length; i++) {
        $table.find('tbody td.test').each(function() {
             $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(settings.columns.test[i][1]), function(index, value) {
                 if ($(this).text() === value) {
                     input += '<option value="' + index + '" selected>' + value + '</option>';
                 } else {
                     input += '<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
                 }
                 //more code...
            });
        });
    }
},
test2: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < settings.columns.test2.length; i++) {
        $table.find('tbody td.test2').each(function() {
             $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(settings.columns.test2[i][1]), function(index, value) {
                 if ($(this).text() === value) {
                     input += '<option value="' + index + '" selected>' + value + '</option>';
                 } else {
                     input += '<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
                 }
                 //more code...
            });
        });
    }
},
```

I'm calling these functions by:

```
columns: {
    test1: [["key", '{"0": "First value", "1": "Second Value"}']],
    test2: [["key", '{"0": "One more value", "1": "One more more value"}']]
}
```

As you see, these two functions are same, only `test` -> `test2`.. Is it possible to make one function and call it with another values for selector? Thanks in advance

Comment: For simple stuff, using params is fine.  But if for any reason you wanted to have 2 functions test1 & test2, you can use a functional closure to create them.  Not sure what the correct term is, but a functional builder would sound about right..

Comment: Extract changeable things as arguments of the function like `function(selector, column)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a param in your test [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), then replace all instances of `test` with that param (when accessing as a property, eg `columns.test`, use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to evaluate the param instead)

```
test: function(selectorValues) {
    for (var i = 0; i < settings.columns[selectorValues].length; i++) {
        $table.find('tbody td' + selectorValues).each(function() {
             $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(settings.columns[selectorValues][i][1]), function(index, value) {
                 if ($(this).text() === value) {
                     input += '<option value="' + index + '" selected>' + value + '</option>';
                 } else {
                     input += '<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
                 }
                 //more code...
            });
        });
    }
},

//invoke using the objects you created (or pass values directly)
test(columns.test1)
```

Comment: Do note that jQuery enables [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) when querying for elements. So `$table.find('tbody td.test, tbody td.test2')` should be a valid selector, possibly easily solving the OP's problem.

Comment: Ok thank you so much, but how can I use this function now? My code: `$("#profileTable").Tabledit({
    columns: {
        identifier: [0, "id"],
        row: [["row"]],
 test1: [["value.."]],
        test2: [['value....']]
    }
});`

Comment: I'm using http://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/ , there I need firstly to write `Draw.columns.test1(); Draw.columns.test2();`

Comment: Looks like I've understand how to use.. Thanks